# AngularJS: directive(template) does not work in tags?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

My task is: group of checkboxes must be checked(all), if checkbox-parent has been checked. Sure, using Angular. OK, what am I doing:

My parent checkbox is gettring the ng-model directive:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-true-value="checked" ng-false-value="" id=""/> {{filterValue.title}}
```

Sub-checkboxes are getting the next:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{checked}} id=""/> {{subNodeValue}}
```

Trying: no check in the last case, however {{checked}} calculates successfully out of the `<checkbox>`.

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPD:**

Sub-checkboxes are created by this:

```
<ul id="id" class="groupList">
                                  <li ng-repeat="subNodeValue in filterValue.subNodesValues">
                                     <input type="checkbox" {{checked}} id=""/> {{subNodeValue}} {{checked}}
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
```

Comment: if want more flexiblity when user unchecks  one of the slaves try this  http://jsfiddle.net/NE9Sf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ngChecked directive instead of doing it that way (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChecked). They have a master/slave checkbox example on there too

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `{{}}` alone inside an element. Use `ng-checked=checked` instead.

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vBftwH4MwkeSiC90AltU?p=preview